# $|G| = pqr^2$, $G$ not simple

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory, simple-groups

If $G$ is a group with cardinality $pqr^2$ and $p,q,r$ different primes $\ge 2$, and given $1+np$ doesn't divide $qr^2$ for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$,

How can you show $G$ is not simple?

I feel like you would use Sylow's Theorem but i'm not sure how to apply it to this scenario.

Comment: Look at the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups.

Answer (score 3):

Let $n_p$ be the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups. By the Sylow theorems we have \begin{align*}
n_p&\equiv 1\pmod p\\
n_p&\mid qr^2
\end{align*}
By the first line we can write $n_p=1+np$ for some $n\in\Bbb N_0$.  By assumption $1+np\nmid qr^2$ if $n>0$, hence $n=0$, *i.e.* $G$ has a unique Sylow $p$-subgroup and is therefore not simple.